# Using lookup tables in Gekko Python Intermediate Equation

Tags: python, arrays, optimization, lookup-tables, gekko

I am trying to add a lookup tables in my GEKKO code as a function of an m.Intermediate variable, but I can't get it to work.  When I run the below code, I get the error:

```
A240[i][j] = m.Intermediate(A240lookup[T[i][j]])

#IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

I tried setting T as an m.Var and as an m.Param (not preferrable) as well, but it did not work.  The solution does work when I use:

```
A240[i][j] = m.Intermediate(p1(T[i][j]))

#instead of:

A240[i][j] = m.Intermediate(A240lookup[T[i][j]])
```

This is not the entire code because I figured the unneccesary stuff would get in the way of an answer. I did notice that APMonitor has a lookup object (http://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/Objects), but I did not know if that would work or even how to implement in my GEKKO model.

Does anyone have an idea to get this problem to work?  Below is my code:

```
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
m.options.SOLVER= 1

n =      4             
p =      2
Tr =     300
temp =11
t = np.linspace(300,1073,15)
Temp = np.array([1023, 973,923,873,823,723, 623, 523, 423, 323, 273])

ATemp240 = np.array([870, 918,956,980,1002,1015,1019,1021,1021.7, 1022.1,1022.4])
p1 = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(Temp,ATemp240,7))

A240lookup = m.Array(m.Param,(1000))

for i in range(1000):
    A240lookup[i].value = p1(i)

F = m.Array(m.Var,(n,p), integer = True) #State in or out
for i in range (n):
    for j in range(p):
        F[i][j].upper = 1
        F[i][j].lower = 0
        
T     = [[[]for j in range(p)]for i in range(n)]
A240  = [[[]for j in range(p)]for i in range(n)]
    
for j in range(p):
      for i in range(1,n):
          T [i][j]   = m.Intermediate(Tr+30*i)
          A240[i][j] = m.Intermediate(A240lookup[T[i][j]])    #I want this
          # A240[i][j] = m.Intermediate(p1(T[i][j]))          #But this is all that works

m.solve(debug=False)
```

HERE IS THE FULL CODE

```
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO()
m.options.SOLVER= 1
m.options.max_iter=3000
# m.options.IMODE=2
# m.options.REDUCE = 3
# m.options.DIAGLEVEL = 1
m.solver_options = ['minlp_print_level 10',\
                    'minlp_maximum_iterations 3000',\
                    'minlp_as_nlp 0',\
                    'minlp_branch_method 2']

# m.options.csv_write=2
n =      120  #time steps (rows)
p =      2    #parts (columns)
ts =     120  #seconds per time step
B =      5    #Block (number of time steps per block)
Tf =     810  #furnace temperature
Tr =     300  #room temperature
H =      .005 #part height (m)
Hsq =    H*H
H2 =     2*H
z =      0
n1 =     -0.6
Pi =     3.141592653539
pi2sqr = (Pi/2)**2
Piz =    Pi*z
aC = 0.000000005
aH = 0.00000005

t = np.linspace(300,1073,15)

T_data = [1023, 973,923,873,823,723, 623, 523, 423, 323, 273]
A240_data = [870, 918,956,980,1002,1017,1019,1021,1021.7, 1022.1,1022.4]
s240_data = [10.4, 11.7, 17, 32, 50, 93, 138, 175, 205, 221, 222]
B240_data = [8.42705, 9.26699, 10.26703, 11.94154, 14.30153, 22.08034, 39.74829, 81.99357, 221.00829, 650, 950]

tc_data = 120*np.arange(0,n)
def qC(t):
    return(sum((4*((-1)**x))/((2*x+1)*Pi)*math.exp((-1*((2*x+1)*Pi/2)**2)*t*aC/(H**2))*math.cos((2*x+1)/2*Pi*z/H)for x in range(n)))
# QC_data =qH(tc_data)
QC_data = np.zeros(n)
for i in range(n):
    QC_data[i] = qC(tc_data[i])
    
def qH(t):
    return(sum((4*((-1)**x))/((2*x+1)*Pi)*math.exp((-1*((2*x+1)*Pi/2)**2)*t*aH/(H**2))*math.cos((2*x+1)/2*Pi*z/H)for x in range(n)))
# QC_data =qH(tc_data)
QH_data = np.zeros(n)
for i in range(n):
    QH_data[i] = qH(tc_data[i])
 
F = m.Array(m.Param,(n,p)) #State in or out
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(p):
        F[i][j].value = 1-((i//B+j)%2)
 
tc   = m.Array(m.Var,(p,n)) # time in current state
QC   = m.Array(m.Var,(p,n)) # Quenching Cool
QH   = m.Array(m.Var,(p,n)) # Quenching Heat
T    = m.Array(m.Var,(p,n)) # Temperature
A240 = m.Array(m.Var,(p,n)) # prediction results
s240 = m.Array(m.Var,(p,n)) # prediction results
B240 = m.Array(m.Var,(p,n)) # prediction results
 
Q     = [[[]for i in range(n)]for j in range(p)] # Quenching
S     = [[[]for i in range(n)]for j in range(p)] # Residual Stress
tr    = [[[]for i in range(n)]for j in range(p)] # Relative Time
Tc    = [[[]for i in range(n)]for j in range(p)] 
var   = [[[]for i in range(n)]for j in range(p)]

for j in range(p):
    m.Equation(tc [j][0] == 0)
    m.Equation(T[j][0] == Tr)
    m.cspline(T[j][0],A240[j][0],T_data,A240_data)
    m.cspline(T[j][0],B240[j][0],T_data,B240_data)
    m.cspline(T[j][0],s240[j][0],T_data,s240_data)
    m.cspline(tc[j][0],QC[j][0],tc_data,QC_data)
    m.cspline(tc[j][0],QH[j][0],tc_data,QH_data) 
    tr   [j][0] = m.Intermediate(0)
    S    [j][0] = m.Intermediate(240)
    Tc   [j][0] = (Tr)

    
    for i in range(1,n):
        m.Equation(tc [j][i] == (tc[j][i-1])*(1-m.abs(F[i][j]-F[i-1][j]))+ts)
        m.cspline(tc[j][i],QC[j][i],tc_data,QC_data)
        m.cspline(tc[j][i],QH[j][i],tc_data,QH_data)
        Q[j][i] = m.Intermediate(QC[j][i]*(1-F[i][j])+(QH[j][i]*F[i][j]))
        Tc    [j][i] = m.Intermediate(Tc[j][i-1]-(m.abs(F[i][j]-F[i-1][j])*(Tc[j][i-1]-T[j][i-1])))
        m.Equation(T [j][i] == Q[j][i]*(Tc[j][i]-(Tr*(1-F[i][j])+(Tf*F[i][j])))+(Tr*(1-F[i][j])+(Tf*F[i][j])))        
        S     [j][i] = m.Intermediate(m.min2(S[j][i-1],(A240[j][i-1]*((tr[j][i-1]+ts+B240[j][i-1])**(n1))+s240[j][i-1])))
        m.cspline(T[j][i],A240[j][i],T_data,A240_data)
        m.cspline(T[j][i],B240[j][i],T_data,B240_data)
        m.cspline(T[j][i],s240[j][i],T_data,s240_data)
        var[j][i] = m.Intermediate(m.min2(S[j][i]-.1,s240[j][i]))
        tr   [j][i] = m.Intermediate(((S[j][i]-var[j][i])/A240[j][i])**(1/n1)-B240[j][i])

m.Minimize(sum(S[j][n-1] for j in range(p)))

m.solve(debug=False)    # solve
```

Comment: Another thought: is there a way to convert a GEKKO Operator to an integer?  If so, then I can use that integer as an index to the lookup table list.

Answer (score 1):

A [cubic spline](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/ObjectCspline) could work for your application. This creates a continuous function from your data from `T_data` and `A240_data`. You may consider bounds on `T` if it becomes a variable to avoid extrapolation error.

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
m.options.SOLVER= 1

n  = 4             
p  = 2
Tr = 300

# Cubic spline
T_data = [1023, 973,923,873,823,723, 623, 523, 423, 323, 273]
A240_data = [870, 918,956,980,1002,1015,1019,1021,1021.7, 1022.1,1022.4]

T    = m.Array(m.Param,(n,p))
A240 = m.Array(m.Var,(n,p))
for j in range(p):
    for i in range(1,n):
        T[i,j].value = Tr+30*i
        m.cspline(T[i,j],A240[i,j],T_data,A240_data)

m.solve()
```

Solver summary

```
 --------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :            6
   Constants    :            0
   Variables    :           16
   Intermediates:            0
   Connections  :           12
   Equations    :            0
   Residuals    :            0
 
 Number of state variables:              8
 Number of total equations: -            6
 Number of slack variables: -            0
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :              2
 
 ----------------------------------------------
 Steady State Optimization with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
 
 Iter    Objective  Convergence
    0  1.25109E-09  1.02206E+03
    1  2.44846E-23  5.37222E-17
    2  2.44846E-23  5.37222E-17
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :   1.350000000093132E-002 sec
 Objective      :   0.000000000000000E+000
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to add the cspline to the model and its runtime has dropped significantly! The only issue now is while the model run time is much quicker, the model setup seems to take much longer.  I saw this question answered, but my model is much https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59791146/using-gekko-optimization-why-is-my-model-builder-so-much-slower-than-my-solver

Comment: I also added the full code at the end of my initial question if there is anything in there that seems off.

Comment: To shorten the issue with cspline, even when I use the code you provided in the answer, but set n=150 and p=2, the model setup is much longer than the model run.

Comment: Thanks for sending your code. It is setting up a new cspline object for every element in the matrix. You may want to set it up as `IMODE=2` if you are doing parameter regression. That way it only needs to create one instance of your model for each data point you are trying to fit. If you aren't doing parameter regression then you'll probably need to keep it this way. Also, you should use `m.abs2` or `m.abs3` instead of `m.abs` that creates a non-differentiable point at `x=0`. You can also try `m.sum()` instead of `sum` to speed up your calculations.